# Rounding error when casting from float to int

Tags: php, rounding, php-7

We have an API that returns prices as string in EUR, e.g. `2.55` or `0.035`. Our database however saves this in cents, so I wrote a really simple method to transform this into cents by just doing

`$cents = (int) ((float) $value['value']['amount'] * 100)`

So for this code

`echo (int) ((float) '2.55' * 100);`

the result should be `255`, right? But somehow, it's `254`. You can test this on your CLI by simply doing

`php -r "echo (int) ((float) '2.55' * 100);"`

When I get the result of `(float) '2.55' * 100)` it's simply `255`, and when I cast this to int it's `255`, why isn't it the same if I cast it to int in the same call?

I mean, I could simply do `'2.55' * 100` and the php casting would calculate this correctly, but I'm still curious why this happens?

Version:

> PHP 7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 11:10:13) ( NTS )

Comment: Then do `echo (float) '2.55' * 100;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a floating point error.

In php, a float value like 255 could actually be something like 254.9999991. You can `round` the value before converting to `int`.

```
echo (int) ( round( (float) '2.55' * 100 ) );
```

This will result to

```
255
```

---

From PHP Doc:

> Warning Floating point precision Floating point numbers have limited
>   precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the
>   IEEE 754 double precision format, which will give a maximum relative
>   error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary
>   arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error
>   propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Serves me right for trusting PHP to do things correctly :p